# Can not install Data Interoperabilty

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, installation, data-interoperability

I have an ArcGis 10.3 license for one year. When I check my authorized extensions I can see I have authorized the Data Interoperability, but when I try to install the extension is not available in the wizard installation. I could not found any executable in the Esri web.

Does anyone know where can I download the Data Interoperability setup.exe?

It's not in the directory installation; I have not a DataInterop folder in it.

[image]

---

the problem is that I can not install it. Once installed, checking it is for activating, but the problem is that does not appear in customize>extensions, I need first to install it.

Comment: After the installation, go to Customize>Extensions.  Tick the Data Interoperability extension - what happens?

Comment: I finally contacted with Esri support. They sent me the exacutable to install data interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that I can not install it. Once installed, checking it is for activating, but the problem is that does not appear in customize>extensions, I need first to install it.

---

I finally contacted with Esri support. They sent me the executable to install data interoperability.